# Reading KML Simple Data to a popup in Open Layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, kml, html

I have created a pop up for markers read from a KML file, however The KML file data is not being read and I assume due to it being in a `<SimpleData>` tag and in a `<name>` tag

How would I be able to read this to get the name of the listed buildings from the file as well as the Grade and Broad Class from this file to the `PopContent` Variable

Pop up Script

```
Omap.on('click', function (evt){
    var feature = Omap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function (feature,layer) {
            return feature;
            });
        if (feature) {
            var Popgeom = feature.getGeometry();
            var Popcoord = Popgeom.getCoordinates();
            
            var PopContent = '<h3>' + feature.get('name') + '</h3>';
            PopContent += '<h5>' + feature.get('Grade') + '<h5>' + '<p>The listed property is a ' + feature.get('BroadClass') + ' building</p>';
            
            content.innerHTML = PopContent;
            overlay.setPosition(Popcoord);
            
            console.info(feature.getProperties());
        }
    });
```

An extract from the KML file:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Kelsterton Hall</name>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#LSB">
        <SimpleData name="id">Cadw_ListedBuildings.fid--3eda8af5_1772a727fac_-6786</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="RecordNumber">1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="DesignationDate">1949/08/08 00:00:00</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Grade">II</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Location">Set back slightly from the road at the junction of Kelsterton Road and Kelsterton Lane.</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="BroadClass">Recreational</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="BroadClass_cy">Hamdden</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Report">http://cadwpublic-api.azurewebsites.net/reports/listedbuilding/FullReport?lang=en&amp;id=1</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>-3.08246357229187,53.2285595916199</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
```

Comment: @TomazicM I didnt even realise I wrote Leaflet, I meant Open Layers

Comment: Are you displaying clustered features?

Comment: @Mike Yes but when you zoom in far enough they are single features so would have data about them right?

Comment: Even when you have a cluster of one you will need to extract the real feature from the cluster, so instead of `return feature;`  you will need `return feature.get('features')[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike stated in the comments

> Even when you have a cluster of one you will need to extract the real feature from the cluster

this means the `return feature;` will need to instead be `return feature.get('features')[0];`

so the code became

```
Omap.on('click', function (evt){
    var feature = Omap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function (feature,layer) {
            return feature.get('features')[0];
            });
        if (feature) {
            var Popgeom = feature.getGeometry();
            var Popcoord = Popgeom.getCoordinates();
            
            var PopContent = '<h3>' + feature.get('name') + '</h3>';
            PopContent += '<h5>' + feature.get('Grade') + '<h5>' + '<p>The listed property is a ' + feature.get('BroadClass') + ' building</p>';
            
            content.innerHTML = PopContent;
            overlay.setPosition(Popcoord);
            
            console.info(feature.getProperties());
        }
    });
```